# obtaining a file from a directory with a unknown middle directory, with python

Tags: python, filesystems

I am trying to look a file that looks who's path looks like this.

```
/foo/{{number}}/{{unknown}}/bar
```

I know what {{number}} is but i do not know what {{unknown}} is, but I do know that there is only one of them.

Lets say number is 1231, when i use the shell command `ls` like this

```
ls /foo/1231/*/bar
```

I get the result I want, for example, it prints out

```
/foo/1231/some_name/bar
```

Now, I want to do get this filename using python, but all my attempts have failed. What I tried first was,

```
os.listdir( "/foo/1231/*/bar" )
```

but it complains that there is no directory `/foo/1231/*/bar`.
I also tried using a python module from `github.com/amoffat/pbs`, but that too say that throws a similar error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbs.py", line 449, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(command_ran, process, call_args, actual_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbs.py", line 140, in __init__
    if rc != 0: raise get_rc_exc(rc)(self.command_ran, self._stdout, self._stderr)
 pbs.ErrorReturnCode_1:

Ran: '/bin/ls /foo/123/*/bar'

STDOUT:



STDERR:

  /bin/ls: /foo/123/*/bar: No such file or directory
```

I then tried using `subprocess.check_output`, but same error occurred.

Then I tried using os.system( "ls /foo/123/*/bar" ), this prints out a meaningful result, there is no way for me to capture it, since on the documentation of `os.system` it says `Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command.`

Does anyone know a way to obtain what I desire? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways suggest themselves.

If there really is only one middle directory, you can extract it like so:

```
beginning = '/foo/1231'
mid = os.path.listdir(beginning)[0]
fullpath = os.path.join(beginning, mid, 'bar')
```

Or you can use the `glob` standard module:

```
fullpath = glob.glob('/foo/1231/*/bar')[0]
```